# Error mounting /dev/sdb1 at media/ on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: mount, hard-drive, ntfs

I am trying to connect my external hard drive but it shows mounting error. I have tried `sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdb1` but it shows following error

```
Mounting volume...
NTFS signature is missing. 
FAILED
Attempting to correct errors... NTFS signature is missing.
FAILED
Failed to startup volume: Invalid argument
NTFS signature is missing.
Trying the alternate boot sector
Unrecoverable error
Volume is corrupt. You should run chkdsk.
```

Comment: NTFS is not a native file-system for GNU/Linux, so I'd do what it suggests, use an OS that natively uses NTFS (ie. run `chkdsk`)

Comment: In other words, boot Windows and run the command in a command prompt or use the GUI native Windows error correction tool.